# Problems installing devtools

Tags: r, devtools

I am a newbie at Rstudio and have problems installing the devtools package. I need to get devtools to install the qss package that I need for data analysis.

I don't know why it doesn't work. I manually installed devtools and it seems to have worked, but if I use library(devtools) it doesnt work, nor can I install the qss package I need.

[image]

Comment: Try running `install.packages("ps")` and make sure that runs without error.

Answer (score 0):

> error:there is no package called 'ps'.

You should install packages with dependences:

```
install.packages("devtools", dep = TRUE)
```

Regards,

Comment: Hi, I just did, it again installed correctly, but doesn't allow me to access devtools. I also restarted RStudio.                                                                    
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'processx', details:
  call: loadNamespace(name)
  error: there is no package called ‘ps’

Comment: Can you edit your message and copy-paste the entire message of installation of devtools? Thank you, Did you also try `install.packages("ps")`as suggested by MrFlick?

Comment: Hi, solved it! Had to install the ps binary package before and then the devtools package, but not the latest version.